# LINQ - Divide series of null-terminated strings

Tags: c#, linq

I'm attempting to improve my LINQ skills, so I've devised this exercise. Suppose I have a byte stream (`IEnumerable<byte>`) of null-terminated strings (I don't know when the stream ends). How do I use LINQ to divide the strings and iterate over them?

Here's some example code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A stream of null-terminated random strings of random length.
    /// </summary>
    static IEnumerable<byte> ByteStream
    {
        get
        {
            var rand = new Random();
            while (true)
            {
                for (var i = rand.Next(2, 10); i > 0; --i)
                {
                    yield return (byte) rand.Next(97, 122);
                }
                yield return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Divides the sequences of null-terminated strings.
    /// </summary>
    static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<byte>> DividedStream
    {
        get
        {
            var word = new List<byte>();
            foreach (var b in ByteStream)
            {
                if (b == 0)
                {
                    yield return word;
                    word = new List<byte>();
                }
                else
                {
                    word.Add(b);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var d in DividedStream)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(d.ToArray()));
        }
    }
```

You'll notice that I'm not actually using LINQ to divide the out the strings: The `DividedStream` property is essentially my own custom-crafted state machine. It seems like I should be able to use `TakeWhile(e => e != 0)` to help me, but I can't seem to figure out how to make use of it in this case.

Do you see a good way I can remove the `DividedString` property and use a LINQ one-liner to do the same thing in my `main`?

EDIT: I've edited the question and code above to attempt to make it clear that I can't slurp the entire buffer of bytes at once. I apologize that I really didn't make this clear at first.

Comment: You can do almost anything with a seeded`.Aggregate` 
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548744(v=vs.110).aspx using new List<List<byte>>() as your seed, or even better, a Queue (Lists are often overkill),  but honestly your current solution is probably cleaner.

Comment: Care to add the aggregate answer? I'm trying to wrap my head around it, but I don't seem to be able to.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really think you can single line LINQ the conversion, but abusing `Aggregate` is always fun:

```
var ans = ByteStream.Aggregate(new List<List<byte>>(), (sa, b) => {
    if (b == 0 || sa.Count == 0)
        sa.Add(new List<byte>());
    if (b != 0)
        sa[sa.Count-1].Add(b);

    return sa;
});

foreach (var d in ans.Select(bl => Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bl.ToArray())))
    Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Of course, you can just use `StringBuilder` instead:

```
var ans = ByteStream.Aggregate(new List<StringBuilder>(), (sa, b) => {
    if (b == 0 || sa.Count == 0)
        sa.Add(new StringBuilder());
    if (b != 0)
        sa[sa.Count - 1].Append((char)b);

    return sa;
}).Select(sb => sb.ToString());

foreach (var d in ans)
    Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Another alternative is to use `GroupBy` but they all pull the whole source.

```
var wc = 0;
var ans = ByteStream.Select(b => new { b, wi = (b == 0) ? wc++ : wc }).GroupBy(bwi => bwi.wi, bwi => bwi.b, (wi, bs) => Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bs.ToArray()));
```

Comment: This answers the original question. Thanks! I didn't make it clear that I can't slurp the entire buffer at once, though (sorry :( ). So I've updated my question and example code. The `Aggregate` seems to need to aggregate over the entire collection of bytes first before allowing the loop to print a line.

Comment: I added a `GroupBy` alternative, but I think the problem is that all the LINQ collecting operators are like SQL in that conceptually the Enumerable is unordered, so they must process everything to do any type of aggregation or grouping.  I think your only answer is to write your own function using yield return as you showed.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach(var d in DividedStream)
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(d.ToArray()));

        Console.WriteLine("new version:\n");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(ByteStream.Select(x => x.Equals(0) ? Environment.NewLine : Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new[] {x}))));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

this is not perfect, because of the Encoding.UTF8 for each letter, but I think you can start with that

**Edit:**

this is shorter but doesn't use UTF8

```
Console.WriteLine(ByteStream.Select(x => x.Equals(0) ? '\n' : (char)x).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this works :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication50
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<byte> bytes = ByteStream;

            byte[] temp = null;
            int position = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Count = '{0}'", bytes.Count());
            do 
            {
                temp =    bytes.Skip(position).TakeWhile(b => b != 0).ToArray();
                position += temp.Length + 1; 
                Console.WriteLine("position {0} : {1}", position,string.Join("",temp.Select(x => x.ToString("X2"))));

            } while (position < bytes.Count()) ;


        }



        /// <summary>
        /// A random number of null-terminated random strings of random length. The final
        /// string is just a null terminator (empty string).
        /// </summary>
        static IEnumerable<byte> ByteStream
        {
            get
            {
                var rand = new Random();
                for (var i = rand.Next(64, 128); i != 0; i--)
                {
                    for (var j = rand.Next(2, 10); j != 0; j--)
                    {
                        yield return (byte)rand.Next(97, 122);
                    }
                    yield return 0;
                }
                yield return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this require skipping over the same elements multiple times (i.e. each time through the `do` loop)? Is that inefficient?

Comment: Yes, but i couldn't think of a better method using straight linq method.

Comment: Is this any better : temp =    bytes.ToList().GetRange(position, bytes.Count() - position).TakeWhile(b => b != 0).ToArray();

Comment: I made a change to the write to display hex values.  It looks like there is still something wrong.  There are blank rows that I haven't been able to figure out.  Need some sleep.  Maybe I will get solution in my dreams.

Comment: I figured it out.  You must be generating multiple 00 in a row.  So the empty rows is when multiple zeros are occurring.

Comment: I changed code again.  The while loop was correct.  It not back in your code.

Comment: Found two issues. 1) Needed to add 1 : position += temp.Length + 1; 2) your for loops should be i-- instead of --i.   Occasionally rand(2,10) was getting 2 and returning 0 bytes.